# Oracle db stop query if date outside range

Tags: database, oracle

I have a large database and use a query like this:

```
...WHERE (DATETIME > '30.10.2014 00:00:00' AND DATETIME < '03.11.2014 00:00:00')
```

My query is already ordered by the field `DATETIME`, so is it possible to break the query if `DATETIME < '03.11.2014 00:00:00'` is first time reached so that oracle don't need to check the remaining rows because they aren't needed and this would safe time?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any index on the table data time field??

Comment: @smn_onrocks what kind of index do you mean? I query a view

Comment: You can use while loop, when ever the condition is false its will exit

Comment: @Mohammed with `while loop` I have problems because my db starts before `30.10.2014 00:00:00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You got basically 3 options here** (ordered from best to worst):

1. If you will create the desired table **partitioned** by `DATETIME`  column, the **optimizer** will scan only the relevant partitions (in range 30.10.2014 00:00:00—03.11.2014 00:00:00) instead of accessing the entire table.
2. Create the table as an **IOT** (Index Organized Table) — this way the table will be stored as an ordered B-Tree.
3. Create an **index on the `DATETIME`**  column. This way, when accessing the column, you will scan the ordered index. This option has a major disadvantage — if the data which is being inserted into this table is "real time sequential data" (I mean that `DATETIME`  column values are always increasing [`sysdate` for example] and not random [date of birth for example]), there will always be a **Hot Block** on your B-Tree index. This will cause **contentions** and probably many **wait events** (dependent on the data insertion rates of course). The way to "solve" this is to create this index **reversed**, but then you will have a big problem performing queries on ranges (like the query you've presented here), because the data will be scattered across the index and not stored sequentially.

So, my best advice for situations like this — work with partitions, this is the best way to work efficiently with big amounts of data on Oracle Databases.

If there's not enough data on this table to consider partitions, then the table is not that big and you can consider options #2, #3.

Best regards.